# Remove site name from <title> tag

Tags: title

My current `<title>` tags are like this:

> Blog post title | Site name

How do I remove "Site name" so that the `<title>` tags will be like this:

> Blog post title

Except, of course, on the front page, where the `<title>` tag should be:

> Site name

Please take into account that I'm a complete Wordpress newbie.

---

Edit: Here's my current `<title>` tag from `header.php`:

```
<title>
<?php
if ( defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' ) ) {
    // WordPress SEO is activated
        wp_title();

} else {

    // WordPress SEO is not activated
    wp_title( '&#124;', true, 'right' );
}
?>
</title>
```

Comment: If you have any SEO plugin active, try to find its title settings. If not, tell us. :)

Comment: I don't have any SEO plugins active.

Comment: Then why do you have the `if ( defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' ) ) {}` conditional?

Answer (score 6):

The best (and easiest) thing to do is to use the `wp_title` *filter*.

First, clean up your call to `<?php wp_title(); ?>` in your template. Replace what you have with this:

```
 wp_title( '&#124;', true, 'right' );
```

Then, in `functions.php` (or in a child Theme `functions.php`; normal caveats apply), add the following:

```
function wpse95147_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_single() || ( is_home() && !is_front_page() ) || ( is_page() && !is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = single_post_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse95147_filter_wp_title' );
```

This filter will completely overwrite the `$title` output in single-page contexts. ([The actual conditional is taken directly from core](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L534), from the `wp_title()` function definition itself.)

Last I checked, WordPress doesn't actually output the site title anywhere in `wp_title()`; so if you're seeing that, something is adding it (perhaps your Theme?). Nevertheless, if you want to output it, just write a complimentary conditional in the above filter; e.g.:

```
function wpse95147_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_single() || ( is_home() && !is_front_page() ) || ( is_page() && !is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = single_post_title( '', false );
    }
    if ( is_front_page() && ! is_page() ) {
        $title = esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse95147_filter_wp_title' );
```

Comment: My parent theme was adding the blog name to the title.  I was able to use this solution to still fix it by simply increasing the priority parameter to the add_filter call.  This ensure that our new filter executes after the parent-theme's filter.  I set the priority to 100: `add_filter('wp_title', 'wpse95147_filter_wp_title', 100);`

Comment: +1 for "something is adding it (perhaps your Theme?)."

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your header.php file

```
<title><?php wp_title();?></title>
```

Add Below code in theme's functions.php file

```
function your_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;
    if(is_front_page()){        
        $title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );   
        return $title;
    } else {
        if ( is_feed() )            
        // Add the site name.
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'your_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Reference:http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score 0):

On my template file header.php I replaced the title line by this

```
<title><?php is_front_page() ? woo_title() : wp_title( '' ); ?></title>
```

In my case I am using a woothemes template, that's why that woo_title() output.

Here, you can check in a single line if you are on home page, if true, you can allow to display the blog/site title, if false output the title without the site name, just will display your post or page title.

Answer (score 0):

i was haveing this issue with posts so i searched the interet and i made a little plugin that remove the blog name from the posts

```
########### start remove blog title from posts #######
 function wp_abdul0201_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $title = single_post_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'wp_abdul0201_wp_title' );
########### end remove blog title from posts #######
```

please notince this code

```
if ( is_single() )
```

it only applies to posts title 
you can add more codition like

```
if ( is_single() || is_archive )
```

here i added archive pages too
i hope you got a general idea of how it works

Answer (score 0):

easiest way Ive found is in Wordpress Settings tab, remove the "Title" of your site. Not the most programmatic, but easiest.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php wp_title(false); ?>
```

Try this and also read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)

`&#124;`indicates vertical bar as separator. true argument stands for $display, whether to display the title or no. Third arugment is position where to put separator.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem? Where is the site name in your answer?